# Why use a restricted Boltzmann machine rather than a multi-layer perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I'm trying to understand the difference between a restricted Boltzmann machine (RBM), and a feed-forward neural network (NN). I know that an RBM is a generative model, where the idea is to reconstruct the input, whereas an NN is a discriminative model, where the idea is the predict a label. But what I am unclear about, is why you cannot just use a NN for a generative model? In particular, I am thinking about deep belief networks and multi-layer perceptrons.

Suppose my input to the NN is a set of notes called x, and my output of the NN is a set of nodes y. In a discriminative model, my loss during training would be the difference between y, and the value of y that I want x to produce (e.g. ground truth probabilities for class labels). However, what about if I just made the output have the same number of nodes as the input, and then set the loss to be the difference between x and y? In this way, the network would learn to reconstruct the input, like in an RBM.

So, given that a NN (or a multi-layer perceptron) can be used to train a generative model in this way, why would you use an RBM (or a deep belief network) instead? Or in this case, would they be exactly the same?

Answer (score 11):

You *can* use a NN for a generative model in exactly the way you describe. This is known as an [autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder), and these can work quite well. In fact, these are often the building blocks of deep belief networks.

An RBM is a quite different model from a feed-forward neural network. They have connections going both ways (forward *and* backward) that have a probabilistic / energy interpretation. You'll need to read the details to understand.

A deep belief network (DBN) is just a neural network with many layers. This can be a large NN with layers consisting of a sort of autoencoders, or consist of stacked RBMs. You need special methods, tricks and lots of data for training these deep and large networks. Simple back-propagation suffers from the [vanishing gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem) problem. But if you do manage to train them, they can be very powerful (encode "higher level" concepts).

Hope this helps to point you in the right directions.

Comment: Thanks. So in the case of an autoencoder vs RBM, is there any intuition as to why it is that an RBM seems to be more effective?

Comment: there is no such thing as "BP through time" in DBN. BPTT is for recurrent networks, not "any" deep architecture

Comment: @Karnivaurus: I don't have enough experience with these (autoencoder vs RBM) to advise when to use which, sorry.

Comment: @lejlot: Thanks, I meant just "back-propagation". Fixed it.